# How do I check an object for negative numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an object that contains the values for two differential equations.

for example:

```
#create equation object
class EquationValues(object):
    x         = 0
    y         = 0
    xMin      = 0
    xMax      = 0
    yMin      = 0
    yMax      = 0
    deltaTime = 0

# Class constructor/initilizer
    def __init__(self, x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime):
        self.x         = x
        self.y         = y
        self.xMin      = xMin
        self.xMax      = xMax
        self.yMin      = yMin
        self.yMax      = yMax
        self.deltaTime = deltaTime

def make_equationValues(x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime):
    equationValues = EquationValues(x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime)
    return equationValues

with open ('inputs.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader   = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    data     = list(reader)
    rowCount = len(data)

while x < rowCount:

    try:
        # Set variables and make sure they are the right format
        x         = float(data[x][0])
        y         = float(data[x][1])
        xMin      = float(data[x][2])
        xMax      = float(data[x][3])
        yMin      = float(data[x][4])
        yMax      = float(data[x][5])
        deltaTime = float(data[x][6])

        # Check for negative input, if negative throw value error
        if (x < 0) or (y < 0) or (xMin < 0) or (xMax < 0) or (yMin < 0) or ( yMax < 0) or (deltaTime < 0):
            raise ValueError
```

how can I check all of the values for negative numbers efficiently?

Currently, I am able to do it by using and if statement in a try/except

for example:

```
if (x < 0) or (y < 0) or (xMin < 0) or (etc):
    raise ValueError
```

This doesn't seem like the best way to do it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Those are not object attributes, they are class attributes.  Can you show us more code?

Comment: Maybe put these values in a container and loop over the container? Also, this class definition is likely not doing what you think it is...

Comment: True, you probably want to define an `__init__` function.

Comment: I uploaded more code for context.  So basically I use .csv output from another program to populate the values in a while loop.  I have the if that I mentioned in the question to check that the input is not negative or non numeric.  The negative part is what I have trouble with doing efficiently though.

Comment: @StephenRauch more code added

Comment: @feltersnach you should really try to grok what Stephen is telling you: those  youve made class-level attributes, but shadow them with instance attributes. You almost certainly don't want to be doing that. Python != Java

Comment: OK, so those are class attributes.  This means that when you instantiate more than one instance of this class they will be sharing these attributes.  You likely should just delete all of the lines `x=0` to `deltaTime = 0`.  You don't need them and they can cause problems

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, you *will be able to instantiate more than one instance of this class at a time*, but OP should still delete those lines. Class level variables simply mean they are accesible by *every* instance, because they are members of the *classes namespace*. But in this case, they are shadowed in *every instance*, making them *invisible in every instance*. Making them useless.

Comment: @StephenRauch not necessarily at all, and in this case, these class-level variables are effectively inaccessible from the instances because they are being shadowed in `__init__`. This is classic "Java in Python" as I like to call it.

Comment: @StephenRauch i deleted them as you suggested. The functionality is still the same, meaning you were correct, thanks.  +1

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you I just learned something.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you nailed it, I pretty much think in java.  I am starting to get away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code actually works (it wouldn't work if these are attributes), you can rewrite it like this:

```
if any(var < 0 for var in (x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime)):
    raise ValueError
```

Since the variables you want to check are just a collection of names, there isn't much more you can do. If they were a list, dictionary or `NamedTuple` etc., there would be more room for improvement.

If the check is supposed to take place in `make_equationValues()` (but why didn't you just put the check in the constructor?) and you have *a lot* more variables than you show, you could streamline the check like this:

```
def make_equationValues(*args):
    if any(var < 0 for var in args):
        raise ValueError

    return EquationValues(*args)
```

But I wouldn't recommend this, because you no longer have an argument signature for your function, which makes it error-prone and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `any` statement to check if any of them is negative.

```
class EquationValues(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime):    
        self.x         = x
        self.y         = y
        self.xMin      = xMin
        self.xMax      = xMax
        self.yMin      = yMin
        self.yMax      = yMax
        self.deltaTime = deltaTime

        negatives = any(v for v in {x,y,xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax,deltaTime} if v < 0)
        if negatives:
            raise ValueError("One variable is negative")

EquationValues(0,0,0,0,0,0,-1) 
# ValueError: "One variable is negative"
```

You can also use `locals()` to get a dict of the current local scope variables.

```
class EquationValues(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime):    
        self.x         = x
        self.y         = y
        self.xMin      = xMin
        self.xMax      = xMax
        self.yMin      = yMin
        self.yMax      = yMax
        self.deltaTime = deltaTime

        if [v for v in locals().values() if isinstance(v, int) if v < 0]:
            raise ValueError("One variable is negative")

EquationValues(0,0,0,0,0,0,-1) 
# ValueError: "One variable is negative"
```

Comment: Instead of materializing a list and checking for empty an empty lists, maybe use `any` with a generator expression instead?

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Changed to use your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

The example here is copied from [Python Descriptors Demystified](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb#Descriptors-(Finally)).

You should use descriptors to store attributes that must be constrained to certain values.  The descriptor can be used to prevent invalid values from being set on any attribute defined using the descriptor class:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class NonNegativeNumber(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.data.get(obj, 0)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError('must be nonnegative value')
        self.data[obj] = val
```

Then your original class would look like:

```
class EquationValues(object):
    x         = NonNegativeNumber()
    y         = NonNegativeNumber()
    xMin      = NonNegativeNumber()
    xMax      = NonNegativeNumber()
    yMin      = NonNegativeNumber()
    yMax      = NonNegativeNumber()
    deltaTime = NonNegativeNumber()

    def __init__(self, x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, deltaTime):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xMin = xMin
        self.xMax = xMax
        self.yMin = yMin
        self.yMax = yMax
        self.deltaTime = deltaTime
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like `self.x = NonNegativeNumber(-1)` still work?

Comment: @tomlynch I am working with this, so far its not working as intended.

Comment: I fixed it.  The descriptor also needs to disallow negative numbers in calls to `__init__`.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the use of descriptors: The constrained values should be the descriptors, i.e. they should be attributes of `EquationValues()`. Your `NonNegativeNumber()` can be replaced by a one-liner. But at least use `__set__` inside `__init__`, your code fails DRY.

Comment: @alexis I have addressed the issues you raised.  Thanks for the feedback.